# How do I update a mapping in ElasticSearch with Java?

Tags: java, search, elasticsearch, mapping, reindex

I have an existing mapping in Elastic Search and this is in live production. Currently, whenever I update the mapping someone else has to manually drop the index and insert reindex everything again. We want a way for Elastic Search to automatically handle update/changed mappings. How can we make this possible with Java?

**EDIT**

The procedure we have for loading the mapping during startup of the application is this:

1. Check if there's an existing mapping
2. If not load new mapping.

As you can see this is very simplistic and as such it will never pick up changed fields/updated mappings. Is it a bad idea to reload the mapping every time the application starts up? Is there some overhead to this? Is there an alternative procedure so it accounts for updated mappings? More importantly, is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: If you check for an existing mapping, why not check for an existing index? The moment you insert your first document you will have a mapping. One proposed solution would be to store the sha1 key of your mapping and when starting check if the sha1 key of the provided mapping is still the same. This only works when you do not dynamically add new fields though. This is coming from the link as mentioned in the other comment. pea53.com/2014/03/versioning-elasticsearch-indices

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to update mapping. You can add new fields, but that is it. If you do want to change the mapping the best way is to copy everything to a new index with the changed mapping. Make sure your application uses an alias that points to the current index

1. Create a new index with new mapping
2. Use scan/scroll/bulk to copy all data to new index
3. Move alias to new index
4. remove old index

I have created a tool to help you with this. It currently uses a GUI, but it is not to hard to copy the right classes to embed it in your own application. You can read about it more in this blog:
http://amsterdam.luminis.eu/2015/01/13/maintain-elasticsearch-the-indexes/

Also look out for the upcoming reindex api, but here yet but I heard good things about it.

Comment: Is there no way for it to automatically detect a change in the mapping?

Comment: For a project I implemented something similar to this: http://pea53.com/2014/03/versioning-elasticsearch-indices/ Working on integrating it into my little project as mentioned in the blog post as well, but not there yet.

Comment: Hi thank you for your time. Please take a look at my updated quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

Not only can you add new fields and insert their values, but you can also update the values of your existing fields.

Use the UpdateRequest class to update the records that you wish (ids) and change the values of certain fields as follows:

```
updateRequest.doc(jsonBuilder().startObject().field("gender", "male").endObject());
```

On the other hand, if you need to create new fields in the existing mapping you can use again the same class as above and a new field will be automatically created:

```
updateRequest.doc(jsonBuilder().startObject().field("newField", "testContent").endObject()
```

If the field "newField" doesn't exist, then a new one will be created. Although you can create it, I doubt that you can specify the type of this new field (after [reading](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-update.html) the documentation).

Furthermore, I am not entirely sure what you mean by updating the **mapping**. even though you can create new fields and update the old ones, if you want to change the type of an existing field, for instance, I don't think it is possible. Have a look also [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) about how to use PUT to update an existing mapping.